# Show that the "folium" is norm closed

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis, normed-spaces, c-star-algebras, locally-convex-spaces

- A **C*-algebra** $\mathfrak{A}$ is a Banach algebra with an involution operation $* : \left\lbrace\begin{aligned} \mathfrak{A} &\longrightarrow \mathfrak{A} \\
    a &\longmapsto a^* \end{aligned} \right.\ $ (antilinear and $\forall\ a,b\in\mathfrak{A},\ (ab)^*=b^*a^*$) such that 
  $ \left\lVert a^*a \right\rVert = \left\lVert a \right\rVert^2\ $ (C* property).
- A **state** $\omega$ on $\mathfrak{A}$ (assumed unital) is a normalized positive linear functional $\omega: \mathfrak{A}\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ i.e.
  \begin{equation}
   \forall\ a\in\mathfrak{A},\enspace \omega(a^* a) \geq 0 \ \text{in partic.}\ \omega(a^* a)\in\mathbb{R}\quad \text{ and }\quad \omega(\mathbb{1}_{\mathfrak{A}})= 1
   \end{equation}
- Define the left action of $\mathfrak{A}$ on $S(\mathfrak{A})$ the set of all states:
  $$b\cdot \omega(-) :\equiv \omega(b^*\cdot -\cdot b)$$
  and the **folium of a state** (usually one defines the folium of a representation) as the set of states "generated by the action" of the algebra, i.e. those of the form
  \begin{equation}
    \omega_{\mathcal{I}} : \left\lbrace \begin{aligned}
     \mathfrak{A} &\longrightarrow \quad\mathbb{C} \\
     a & \longmapsto \sum_{i\in \mathcal{I}} \omega \left(b^*_i \cdot a \cdot b_i\right)
     \end{aligned} \right. \qquad\text{with }\ (b_i)_{i\in \mathcal{I}}\in\mathfrak{A}\ \text{ s.t. }\ \sum_{i\in \mathcal{I}} \omega(b_i^*\cdot b_i)=1 
   \end{equation}

*Remark:* $\mathcal{I}$ is a priori not supposed to be countable but $\sum_{i\in \mathcal{I}} \omega(b_i^*\cdot b_i)=1 $ is a bounded sum of positive numbers, and one can show that only countable many summands are non-zero.

**Question:** i want to show that the folium of a state is closed in the norm of $\mathfrak{A}^*$, the Banach space dual of $\mathfrak{A}$, i.e. 
 $ \left\lVert \omega \right\rVert_{\mathfrak{A}}:= sup_{\left\lVert a\right\rVert=1} |\omega(a)|$

(This statement holds for the usual definition of folium, but in fact I originally wanted to check that the folium of a state as defined here is the folium of the GNS representation of that state.)

**Ideas?** a state $b\cdot \omega$ with $b$ such that $\omega(b^*b)=1$ is in the folium and this latter is generated by convex linear combinations of such states, i.e. is it the convex hull of such states. I checked that one cannot conclude from this that the folium is closed, but maybe one can say something if it is a subset of the set of all states $S(\mathfrak{A})$ which is known to be weak-* compact, in particular norm closed.

Comment: This is probably wrong, and one should take the closed convex hull of the set of $\omega_{\mathcal{I}}$ as defined (norm closure), in order for the definition to coincide with the usual one.
I had also thought, maybe the convex hull of a compact set would be compact, but it probably only holds only in finite dimension, cf. also this [link](https://books.google.fr/books?id=4hIq6ExH7NoC&pg=PA185&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) from [this question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/156321/convex-hulls-of-compact-sets). The books seems great.